# Как конвертировать CIDR маску подсети в hex формат?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hex

Подскажите, как получить значение равное `FFFFFFFE` получается вывести только `EFFFF` в обратном порядке и без первых двух символов `FF`

Источник кода: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3152101/7549532)

```
var cidr = 23;
var zeroBits = 32 - cidr;
var result = uint.MaxValue;

result &= (uint)((((ulong)0x1 << cidr) - 1) << zeroBits);
result = (uint)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((int)result);

textBoxHex.Text = result.ToString("X");
```

Comment: Решил так: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55440867/7549532 (без использования `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder`) если есть способ проще, подскажите.